# BOOST ASIO load key.pem with passphrase

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, boost-asio, pem

Currently I'm working with this:

```
...
    ctx.use_certificate_chain_file("./C/cert.pem");
    ctx.use_private_key_file("./C/key.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
    ctx.load_verify_file("./C/ca.pem");
...
```

So far everything works perfect, but what I really need to do is load the same key.pem but with a passphrase, Looking at asio docs found [ssl::context::set_password_callback](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/set_password_callback.html) wich according to the info calls [SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb.html) and allows to handle encrypted PEM files, please remember that I'm much more familiarized with high level languages like python, so c++ is not my forte

any help is appreciated, Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be familiar with callbacks from python.

First define the callback function:

```
using namespace boost::asio;

// this function is called to obtain password info about an encrypted key
std::string my_password_callback(
    std::size_t max_length,  // the maximum length for a password
    ssl::context::password_purpose purpose ) // for_reading or for_writing
{
    std::string password; 
    // security warning: !! DO NOT hard-code the password here !!
    // read it from a SECURE location on your system
    return password;
}
```

Then set the callback with `set_password_callback()`:

```
// set the callback before you load the protected key
ctx.set_password_callback(my_password_callback);
// ...
// this will call my_password_callback if a password is required
ctx.use_private_key_file("key.pem",ssl::context::pem);
```

If you want to use a class method as callback,

```
class server {
    std::string password_callback(); //NOTE: no parameters
    // ...
};
```

you can use `boost::bind()` to set the callback:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void server::startup() {
    ctx_.set_password_callback(
        boost::bind(&server::password_callback,this) );
    // ...
}
```

In either case, a `boost::system::system_error` exception (based on `std::exception`) will be thrown 
if the key could not be decrypted, possibly because the password was wrong or the file could not be found.